# How can I monitor Backbone ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I thought this would be easy b.c. Backbone uses jQuery and has a single access point I thought I could just do this:

```
  Backbone.ajax = function() {
    var xhr = Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments); 
    // xhr.addEventListener("loadend", loadEnd);
    return xhr;
  };
```

but for some reason I can not load an event listener to the xhr object as I normally do.

I get an error stating that addEventListener is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

See [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object.

It is not exactly the native XMLHttpRequest, so it might not behave exactly like the native one. There is no guarantee that it exposes methods like `addEventListener` unless it's documented. If you want to set something globally it's safer to use [`jquery.ajaxsetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)